# Type describing alternative keys

Tags: typescript, types

I have an object that looks like this:

```
const object = { a: 10, an: 20 };
```

The object is not defined by me, but it's an object that I receive from somewhere else. The keys of this object can be taken from:

```
const keys = {
    /**
     * A long name that describes what "a" stands for.
     */
    aReallyLongName: "a",

    /**
     * Another long name that describes what "an" stands for.
     */
    anotherReallyLongName: "an"
};
```

To obtain the value `10` from `object`, I write:

```
object[keys.aReallyLongName] // 10
```

Is there any way of using `aReallyLongName` in a type-safe way to refer to `object`'s `a` property?

---

Note that I'd like a way to use the long names to refer to the short names, not the other way around. Basically I'd like a way to refer to `a` from `object` by the name `aReallyLongName` instead of `a`, in a type-safe way (even as an alias, it doesn't have to be in a `keys` object).

I'd like a way in which something like `object.aReallyLongName` would be compiled to `object.a`, and for the compiler to know that the value is supposed to be a `number`.

Maybe something like this:

```
interface Data {
    /**
     * A long name that describes what "a" stands for.
     */
    "a" as "aReallyLongName": number;

    /**
     * Another long name that describes what "an" stands for.
     */
    "an" as "anotherReallyLongName": number;
}

object.aReallyLongName // compile to: object.a
```

---

## Use Cases

### 1. Mapping data received from an API or library

An API could return abbreviated keys, keys that don't look right in the context of the project, or keys that need more description. For example, an API might return

```
{ "prop": { "cat": "Test", "long_description": "Lorem" } }
```

It would be nice to be able to define an interface that describes this data structure, but at the same time use `properties` instead of `prop`, `category` instead of `cat` and `description` instead of `long_description`.

### 2. Abbreviations for MongoDB document keys

To optimize storage in MongoDB, one way would be to abbreviate the keys of a document. A document could look like this:

```
{ "p": { "n": "John Doe", "a": "Example Street" } }
```

Again, it would be nice to be able to describe this document's keys and value types, but at the same time use `person` instead of `p`, `name` instead of `n` and `address` instead of `a`, without having to create an ORM layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the **keyof** operator.

It would look something like this (I made keys an indexable object so it's properties can have any name but you can specify them instead if needed):

```js
const object = { a: 10, an: 20 };

type Keys = keyof typeof object;

const keys: { [index: string]: Keys } = {
    aReallyLongName: "a",
    anotherReallyLongName: "an"
};
```

With this typing giving values that are not keys of **object** gives you a compilation error:

```js
const object = { a: 10, an: 20 };

type Keys = keyof typeof object;

const keys: { [index: string]: Keys } = {
    aReallyLongName: "B",
    anotherReallyLongName: "xn"
};
```

You can read more about this in the Advanced Types section of the handbook [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Alternatively you could just use a decorator class that defines getters and setters with different names than the original object.

It would look something like this.

```js
const object: { a: number, an: number } = { a: 10, an: 20 };

class ObjectDescriptor {
    constructor(private original: typeof object) {

    }

    public get AReallyLongName() {
        return this.original.a;
    }

    public set AReallyLongName(value) {
        this.original.a = value;
    }

}
```

And you will be able to access it like this.

```js
let descriptor = new ObjectDescriptor(object);
descriptor.AReallyLongName;
```

Comment: This would make `keys` type safe, but it wouldn't make `object` type safe. I can still write `object["c"]` and there's no way to know which of the keys from `keys` (not which values) I can use. What I'd like is a way of using `aReallyLongName` in a type-safe way to refer to a property on `object`, not the other way around.

Comment: I don't think typescript allows you to type that accessor only when you do object.c it will complain. Probably because it's runtime values.

Comment: And the way to type that is to restrict the values of the keys object to be just keys of the original object.. which is what I proposed.

Comment: my answer makes it so the values of the keys object can only be keys of the object object. that won't stop you calling object['an'] though.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, but unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've added another example using a class and getters. It's more verbose but but gives you better control.

Comment: That's closer to what I need, but it introduces a class, it doesn't describe `object`'s type.

Comment: indeed, I'm just not sure you can do what you want the way you want it done. Not in typescript at least.. Maybe someone else does.